# Librerías en python (anaconda)

Tags: python, pip

Uso anaconda y normalmente para descargar y posteriormente utilizar librerías, bastaba con escribir en la terminal

`pip install package`,

pero me da este error:

> Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
>       status=None)) after connection broken by     'ConnectTimeoutError(
>
> ```
> object at 0x000000000580E0F0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect 
> timeout=15)')': /simple/findspark/
> ```

Lo que quiero saber es si hay un método para solucionarlo, o de lo contrario, otra manera de descargar librerías.

Gracias

Comment: Con cual librería? alguna específica? todas?

Answer (score 1):

Parece ser un problema de conexión debido a tu red, firewall. Intenta desactivando tu antivirus o si estás usando proxy intenta con:

> pip install --proxy domain\user:password@proxyaddress:port Nombre_Paquete

Ref.: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4417

---

Otra forma de instalar las librerias sería manualmente:

> conda install /packages-path/packages-filename.tar

Ref.: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/install-packages/

Comment: con eso se solucionó, muchas gracias!!